# Error handling in VBA - on error resume next

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
ErrNr = 0
For Rw = StRw To LsRw 'ToDo speed up with fromrow torow
    If Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh).Cells(Rw, TsCl)) = 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh).Cells(Rw, TsCl).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        ErrNr = ErrNr + 1
    End If
Next
```

My problem is if there is an error on the page, my code is not running after that. I think the solution should be with:

```
On Error Resume Next
N = 1 / 0    ' cause an error
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    N = 1
End If
```

But I don't know how to use this code.

Comment: What color should it be if there is an error in the cell?

Comment: Don't. No. `On Error Resume Next` simply ***swallows*** errors. You need to figure out how to *avoid* the error to begin with.  On another note, it seems you could accomplish this with [Conditional Formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html).

Comment: You also might want to read through some of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error-handling+vba?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have interpreted your requirement as to how to handle common worksheet errors when looping through a range of cells and examining the values. If you attempt to look at a cell that contains an error (e.g. #N/A, #DIV/0!, #VALUE!, etc) you will get something like:

```
Runtime error '13':
Type mismatch.
```

These can be caught with VBA's [IsError function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s55kc30t).

```
Dim rw As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh)
    For rw = StRw To LsRw
        If IsError(.Cells(rw, 1)) Then
            .Cells(rw, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        ElseIf Not CBool(Len(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2)) Then
            .Cells(rw, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        End If
    Next rw
End With
```

[image: IsError against worksheet errors/values]

In the above, I am catching the cells with an error and coloring them green. Note that I am examining them for errors *before* I check for a zero length.

Comment: I am using this solution to help my error catching code if a Vlookup cant find anything and I get the error "Expected Array". do you have to use the `.Cells(row, col)` format?

Comment: If you are using worksheetfunction.vlookup or application.worksheetfunction.vlookup then switch to application.vlookup. The IsError or a variant will catch no match errors.

Comment: I am using the Vlookup within the spreadsheet. The VBA code pastes the lookup value into a cell, then stores all the return values as variables as well. I did it this way to avoid looping through 60,000 lines looking for the lookup value.

Comment: This may be too involved to be resolved in comments. Please post a new question with all the details.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you want to do.

- `On Error Resume Next` will ignore the fact that the error occurred. This is a great way to get your code to execute to completion, but *will just about guarantee that it **won't** do what you want*.
- `On Error Goto 0` is the default response. It will pop up the error message that VBA is generating
- `On Error Goto <label>` will cause your code to jump to a specified label when an error occurs and allows you to take an appropriate action based on the error code.

The last option, `On Error Goto <label>` is usually the most useful, and you'll want to do some digging on how to best use it for your application.

[This site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) is where I got the details above from, and is usually the first results that comes from [Googling for "excel vba on error"](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+on+error&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I've used that reference myself a number of times.

Answer (score 6):

I generally try to avoid On Error Resume Next as it will try to continue no matter what the error (there are some cases where it's useful though).

The code below passes all errors out of the procedure where they can be handled on a case by case basis.

```
Sub test1()

    Dim n As Double

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

        n = 1 / 0  ' cause an error

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 11 'Division by zero
            n = 1
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        Case 13 'Type mismatch

        Case Else
            'Unhandled errors.
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure test1."
            Err.Clear

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: As @Freeman said a few seconds before I posted - and Chip Pearsons site is probably where I got the above code from in the first place all those years ago.