# excel vba - convert iferror/find formula to vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following excel formula

```
IFERROR(MID(B7;FIND(" ";B7)+1;1);"")
```

I want to convert this now to VBA, but I have trouble integrating the Find function here. This is what I have so far

```
IfError(Mid(Sheets("MySheet").Cells(x, 7),Sheets("MySheet").Cells(x, 7).Find " " + 1, 1), "")
```

But that's clearly not correct. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I think your cells() should be `cells(7,x)`  IfError is a worksheet function, so you'll need like `WorksheetFunction.IfError(x,y)`  In VBA you could say `x=left(spit(cells(7,x)," ")(1),1)` and use error checking to handle if there are no spaces or a check first `if instr(1,cells(7,x)," ")>0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error handling in VBA - on error resume next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390673/error-handling-in-vba-on-error-resume-next)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like so, called like `get_first_char_after_space("testing xys")`

```
Function get_first_char_after_space(strInput As String) As String

If InStr(1, strInput, Chr(32)) > 0 Then
    get_first_char_after_space = Left(Split(strInput, Chr(32))(1), 1)
Else
    get_first_char_after_space = vbNullString
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution for IFERROR at the following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29390944/6908282.

And VBA has a Range.Find menthod which you can use to replaicate FIND formula.
Documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF to do the job of your worksheet function. As you see, an error can be avoided in VBA. I presume that the entire function could be compressed into one line but whatever benefit that might entail would come at the cost of readability and possibly stability. As it is, the code is very robust. It easily transplants into a bigger project as, no doubt, is your intention.

```
Function NextChar(Cell As Range) As String
    ' IFERROR(MID(B7;FIND(" ";B7)+1;1);"")

    Dim Txt As String
    Dim n As Integer

    Txt = Cell.Value
    n = InStr(Txt, " ")
    If n Then NextChar = Mid(Txt, n + 1, 1)
End Function
```

If called from the worksheet the function would be `=NextChar(B7)`. Called from code it would be `Debug.Print NextChar(Sheet1.Cells(7, 2))`

Comment: FindBlank ?? should be NextChar

Comment: @CDP1802. Yes indeed! Thank you. I renamed the function just before posting :-)